# Selenium script with chrome driver

Tags: selenium-grid

I am exporting a jar of selenium script which uses chrome driver in my PC, but when i am using the same script on other computer,the script is not executable,The exception says unable to find chrome driver,I there any way by which i can bundle chrome driver in the same jar Please help.

Comment: Could you please add code that you are trying to run.

Comment: What are using to build the jar? You will need to use "bundle all dependencies" to accomplish this.